# I want to play https videos in android app

Tags: android, https, youtube, android-videoview, vitamio

I want to play videos from secure urls (https) in android.
I have used vitamio player but this player play videos from just http connection not https.
Here is my code.

```
Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext());

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.tvplay);
    Log.d("url=", getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    init();

}

public void init() {
    load = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.load);
    empty = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    loading();
}

private void loading() {
    load.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void loadComplete(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.resume();
}

private void error(String msg) {
    load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (msg != null)
        empty.setText(msg);
}
```

Plese Help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vitamio is not supporting to https directly. You may need to recompile the library with OpenSSL. Or use other SSL supported open source players